# Using Blender to create an equirectangular texture for texturing parts of a sphere later on

Tags: texturing, uv

The basic task is as following: I want to texture a high-resolution satellite picture compilation onto a sphere, ideally also combining this with existing water mask and topography bump map. The latter two would come from NASA's "Blue Marble" collection:
https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/collection/1484/blue-marble

The primary texture, however, would come from ESA's "Cloud-free Europe":
https://www.esa.int/ESA_Multimedia/Images/2018/04/Cloud-free_Europe
That's the most high-res picture of Europe I found....

Now the difficulties: NASA's "Blue Marble" pictures are in equirectangular form and can be directly applied to an UV-sphere in order to get a decent "planet Earth" with a few clicks. However, the ESA Picture is not directly suitable. The point is that the edges of the the image are vertically and horizontally aligned with longtitudal resp. latitudal grid lines. IMHO this makes it equirectangular, in fact. However, there is some vertical stretching issue that forbids its mapping onto an UV sphere. I did attach a blender-screenshhot that is showing the issue. There are actually two spheres one on each other. On one sphere I mapped the full water mask of earth. On the other sphere I mapped "Cloud-free Europe" approximately there where it is supposed to be (not very precisely, but precisely enough to illustrate the issue). I made the water mask a bit transparent so that the europe-mask becomes visible. While the horizontal mapping appears to be ok, the vertical mapping is scrap.

For instance the Black Sea of the mapped satellite picture is far too south in comparison to where it is on the water mask. However, the very south end and the very north end of the mapped satellite picture appear to be aligned more or less ok. In general, the south part needs to be vertically stretched, while the north part needs to be vertically compressed. This is also the typical perception of equirectangular pictures such as this one here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Europe_satellite_image_location_map.jpg

Now my actual question: In the Cylces Renderer there is the option to change the camera type to "Panoramic" and the lense to "Equirectangular". I read somewhere that this can be used in order to create an equirectangular image for later texturing. I made some experiments by mapping the original picture onto a plane and "film" this plane with an equirectangular camera lens. However, I was not yet successful here. I also do not really understand the setting of the min and max angles there. However, since the picture boundaries are already aligned as they have to be, and the equirectangular lens is introducing some curvature, my feeling is that this is not the way to go.

What I can imagine to possibly work with maybe more chance rather than the equirectangular camera lens: Create a cylindrical shape,  resp. a segment of a cylinder. The angle of the segment does exactly match the supposed vertical stretch of the image (which is from about 32 degrees north to about 78 degrees north, so the angle is 78-32 = 46 degrees). Then I map the image onto the surface of that cylindrical surface. Then I "picture" that with the camera in orthographic view facing the cylindrical surface properly. The resulting picture would be the properly stretched/compressed texture image. Difficult to describe here in words.... I'm not sure whether this is really working, but I'll try to do this and report here whether it worked out or not. Nonetheless I wanted to ask for these things here right now. Perhaps there are some other damn-easy solutions for that problem I just don't know....

Thanks,
Mario

[image: Illustration of a non-fitting satellite picture mapping]

Update: Ok, I tried what I described above. Though, I did not use a part of a cylinder but a curved plane. This is the essential setup:
[image]

The lower end of the plane ends at an angle (in terms of latitude) that is more or less matching the bottom latitude of the satellite picture (30 degrees north here). To the top/north the plane is stretching up to where the upper latitude of the satellite picture is (here 72 degrees north). The width of the plane should be secondary here, as this will be stretched during later mapping the texture automatically. I did just choose it in a certain relation to the south-north stretch in order to not loose resolution. The camera is set to orthographic (very important) and is picturing the scene from a right angle. Horizontal and vertical position of the camera is secondary.

Ok, I did render the camera view, cut the little empty areas at the borders later on (because the camera bounds are difficult to be set exactly to the texture bounds; but that's not that important) and I mapped the result again together with the water mask onto UV-shperes. This is the result:

[image]

Hmmm, although much much better, still not ok. Apart from the fact that there is a slight logtitudal shift that I should correct by aligning the texture better from west to east, there is also still quite a big of latitudal shift. The problems do already start at the mediterranien coastline of Africa. Central Europe needs do be shifted north quite much. I'll try to check the south and north bounds of the picture with more precision....

Maybe some of you that know a bit more about this matter than me can comment on my method to stretch the picture accordingly. Perhaps there is also still some fundamental issue with it.... However, I think that this is the way to go. But it would be good if this could be done in this project with the combination of the water mask, so that there can be done some sort of "live-tweaking" resp. trial&error. Right now this is a rather nasty two-pass process (doing the transformation in one project and checking the result in the other project).

One more update: Probably I found the remaining puzzle or at least a smoking gun.... I believe that NASA's full "Blue Marble" textures take into account that Earth is is not really like a sphere but is somewhat flat on the poles (it's an ellipsoid, mathematically spoken). This means that the plane with the "Cloud-free Europe" needs to be curved around an ellipse rather than a circle. This will change the final warping slightly. Also the length of the plane (the south-north stretch) will probably change. I have to check that next....

One more update: I'm giving up on that now :-(
Taking care about the ellipsoid appears to not really make a difference here. Maybe this can be even totally ignored here. I don't know what's wrong with that "Cloud-free Europe" picture or what's wrong with my method. The picture stretches perfectly from 25W to 45E and 30N to 72N, and it can be fit horizontally perfectly with existing textures. But there's no way to transform it so that it fits vertically as well. Anyway, I'm going with other material then....

**I have to come back....**

Although I migrated to a different source of a satellite picture that I can directly map onto parts of a sphere, I also wanted to map regular card material onto a sphere. Guess what: The problems I was running into were the same. However, things are more clear to me and my initial approach of mapping the initial image to a bend plane seems to be not complete waste. Maps are usually in Mercator-projection. I guess that the "Cloud-free Europe" is also in Mercator-projection. In fact, what I did with this setup by warping a plane with the image on a circular path is exactly what is needed here. This is implementing a transformation from Mercator into Equirectangular. With the maps I tried to convert the issues were similar. However, I did spot a technical issue with my Blender setup. My plane was rather badly curved because I had a rather low "Render U" for the BezierCircle settings. After I did change this things were much better. Not perfect, but very much acceptable (also taking into account, that the maps might be not that ultra-precise). So apparently this method is working. Btw., taking care about Earth's ellisoid-shape did neither improve nor worsen the situation in my tests.

I did come back to "Cloud-free Europe" and did test again with a more smooth plane. Things did not change as hoped, however. I guess that this satellite picture is not as technically correct as it would be needed for such use.

Comment: Why not just edit the Europe picture into place with GIMP?

Comment: @TheLabCat Sure the picture can be edited in GIMP "somehow". The question is whether the well-defined curving/warping can be done in GIMP. I don't think that GIMP can accomplish that. The point is that GIMP or any other photo editing program is just throwing around pixels. That doesn't mean GIMP is bad in any way - it's just not useful here. However, Blender allows to be "physically correct", as it resembles a 3D-world. But in case you know a way how to accomplish the needed transformation in GIMP - my ears and eyes are open....